# Error on comparing IO Int inside of a lambda

Tags: haskell, io, lambda, int

I have a small block of code here that I want to use in an if statement. The code is

```
getRandomInt :: (Int, Int) -> IO Int
getRandomInt (a, b) = do
    g <- newStdGen
    return . fst $ randomR (a, b) g
```

then further down...

```
if ((getRandomInt (0,1)) >>= (\x -> x == 1))
```

Under my understanding, this should compile down to `randomInt == 1` and be usable inside of an if statement. Instead; I get this error:

```
word.hs:30:21:
    Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `IO b0'
    In the expression: ((getRandomInt (0, 1)) >>= (\ x -> x == 1))
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      if ((getRandomInt (0, 1)) >>= (\ x -> x == 1)) then
          getRandomVowel : (getWord $ len - 1)
      else
          getRandomConsonant : (getWord $ len - 1)
    In the expression:
      do { if ((getRandomInt (0, 1)) >>= (\ x -> x == 1)) then
               getRandomVowel : (getWord $ len - 1)
           else
               getRandomConsonant : (getWord $ len - 1) }
```

Sorry for any blatant misunderstandings, I have just started learning Haskell yesterday.

Answer (score 5):

The type of `(>>=)` is `Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. In this case `m = IO`.

So you have two problems:

Firstly, `\x -> x == 1` would return a `Bool`, not an `IO Bool`, so it doesn't fit as the second argument to `(>>=)`.

You could trivially fix that by changing it to `\x -> return (x == 1)`, but that's not a very clean solution and you then find that the result is of type `IO Bool`, rather than `Bool`.

That's what the type error is telling you - `if` expects a `Bool` argument but it got `IO something`.

The cleanest solution is to lift the `getRandomInt` call out into a separate `<-` line:

```
x <- getRandomInt (0,1)
if x == 1 then ...
```

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested, but this only gave me a rather more cryptic error which I have edited into the first post.

Comment: That's a different problem in `getWord`. Try changing its type to `IO [Char]` rather than `[IO Char]` - those are two very different things. You'll also need some `return`s in the body around each branch of the `if` and in the `otherwise` case.

Comment: Oh, I do see what I did wrong in the rest of the function. Once I fix the rest of it I will look more into this error. Unless this error stems from this function being broken.

Comment: Also, you should really ask different questions for different problems in cases like this, otherwise it becomes quite hard to follow the question/answer flow.

Comment: I wasn't aware that the separate error was part of a different problem. I'll edit it out of the question.

Comment: Yeah, it's tricky when you don't know what's wrong. One thing that can help is if you ask questions where someone can reproduce the problem just by copying and pasting the code.It makes it easier to answer in general (though in this case the problem was obvious to any experienced Haskeller), and it also makes it easy to tell when the initial problem really has been solved or not.

Answer (score 1):

`((getRandomInt (0,1)) >>= (\x -> x == 1))` doesn't work, because `>>=` has the type (specialized to `IO` here): `IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b`, but `(\x -> x==1)` has the type (specialized to `Int` here): `Int -> Bool`, so your types don't match. *This* problem can be solved quite easily, there's actually a function to apply a pure function here: `liftM :: Monad m => (a->b) -> m a -> m b` (which is pretty much equivalent to `fmap`, if you ever heard of that).

Second problem is that even if you got that sorted out, you can still not use an `IO Bool` in place of a `Bool` in your if statement (which is what the error is complaining about; The type checker didn't actually get that far before it figured out the type can't possibly be right).

My personal suggestion would be to stay clear of `IO` for now if possible; It doesn't work exactly like you'd be used to from imperative languages, and you'd need a slightly better understanding of Haskell to completely grok it.